# Sum of unit vectors always has a binary span after constrained permutations

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, permutations, coding-theory, combinatorics-on-words

Conjecture:

> Let $e_1 = (1,0,\ldots,0), \ldots , e_{m_1+m_2} = (0,\ldots,0,1)$ be the unit vectors of the standard basis $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^{m_1+m_2}$.
>   An enumeration $ E \cup -E = \{f_1, \ldots, f_{2(m_1+m_2)}\}$ is given, together with an index $l \in \{1, \ldots, 2(m_1+m_2) \}$.
>
> There exist permutations $ \sigma_1, \sigma_2 $ (whose composition $ \sigma_2 \circ \sigma_1$ we indicate with $\sigma$) and indices $j, k \neq l$ such that
>
> 1. $ \{ \sum_{i=1}^l f_{\sigma (i)}, \sum_{i=1}^j f_{\sigma (i)}, \sum_{i=1}^k f_{\sigma (i)} \}$ is a linearly dependent set;
> 2. $\sigma_1 (i)= i$ if $f_i \notin \{ e_1, \ldots, e_{m_1}\}$;
> 3. $\sigma_2 (i)= i$ if $f_i \notin \{ e_{m_1+1}, \ldots, e_{m_1+m_2}\}$.

As an example, I take $m_1=m_2=3$, and put a possible instance of the unit vectors $f_1, \ldots, f_{12}$ on the rows of a table, separating the components of each vector with a vertical line:

$$
\begin{array}{c|ccc|ccc}
f_1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
f_2 &  0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
f_3 &  0 & 0 & 0 & -1& 0 & 0 \\
f_4 &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1& 0 & \star \\
f_5 &  0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
{\color{yellow} {f_6}} &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
{\color{yellow} {f_7}} &  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
{\color{yellow} {f_8}} &  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
{\color{blue} {f_9}} &  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
{\color{blue} {f_{10}}} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
{\color{blue} {f_{11}}} & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
f_{12} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{array}
$$

The star position indicates the given index $l$ (i.e., $4$), while the blue-colored rows are the only ones $\sigma_1$ can touch, being those whose first $m_1=3$ components have a $1$ occurring.
Similarly, the yellow-colored rows are the only ones $\sigma_2$ is allowed to shuffle.

Since $f_1 + f_2 + f_3 + f_4 = - (f_6 + f_7 + f_9 + f_{10})$, it suffices to take the identity as $\sigma_1$, while $\sigma_2$ only swaps $f_6$ with $f_8$. The wanted $j$, $k$ are then $6$ and $10$.

This problem is a (hopefully correct) reformulation of a graph-theoretical one, which I hope is more amenable to be proven. I feel there should be a proof for this; however, my first attempts looking at simple induction schemes and matroid theory failed. Hints on how to attack the conjecture would be very welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Note: I do have a geometric proof that switches to the continuum and exploits continuity. However, this proof is complicated and, most importantly, is not extensible to more than two permutations, which is important for the problem at hand. The reformulation given in this post is much simpler, hence I was hoping it would allow me to attack the problem more easily and effectively.

Comment: Also, the question's title reads a bit awkward to me, but I couldn't come up with a better one. Even suggestions in this respect are welcome!